# ORA-01722: invalid number when insert a row

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have an oracle trigger that gives me invalid number error when i want to insert a row. I think something wrong with one of the comparison operator. I tried to edit them but did not work. It could be easy for someone who spends more time with databases than me.
My column types are:
id, question_id, answer_id, student_id - number, varchar2, varchar2,varchar2.

```
create or replace 
trigger results_insert
   after INSERT
   ON results
   FOR EACH ROW DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING
   THEN
        MERGE INTO results rs
        USING (select :new.id id, :new.question_id qid, :new.answer_id aid, :new.student_id stid 
        from dual) t1
          ON (t1.qid = rs.question_id AND t1.stid = rs.student_id)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET rs.answer_id = t1.aid
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (id, question_id, answer_id, student_id)
          VALUES (t1.id, t1.qid, t1.aid, t1.stid);
   END IF;  
   COMMIT;
END;
```

My insert statement:

```
insert into results(id,question_id, answer_id, student_id) values (1,'qst1', 'answ2', 'stud3');
```

[image: results table]

DDL:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  File created - Monday-April-19-2021   
--------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table RESULTS
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "ANSWER_ID" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
    "QUESTION_ID" VARCHAR2(5 CHAR), 
    "STUDENT_ID" VARCHAR2(9 CHAR)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index SYS_C007820
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "BIGFIVE"."SYS_C007820" ON "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index UQ_RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "BIGFIVE"."UQ_RESULT" ON "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" ("QUESTION_ID", "STUDENT_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table RESULTS
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "UQ_RESULT" UNIQUE ("QUESTION_ID", "STUDENT_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" MODIFY ("STUDENT_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" MODIFY ("QUESTION_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" MODIFY ("ANSWER_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Ref Constraints for Table RESULTS
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "RESULTS_ANSWERS_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("ANSWER_ID")
      REFERENCES "BIGFIVE"."ANSWERS" ("ANSW_ID") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "RESULTS_QUESTIONS_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("QUESTION_ID")
      REFERENCES "BIGFIVE"."QUESTIONS" ("QST_ID") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "RESULTS_STUDENT_DIM_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID")
      REFERENCES "BIGFIVE"."STUDENT_DIM" ("STU_ID") ENABLE;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Trigger RESULTS_INSERT
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS_INSERT" 
   after INSERT
   ON results
   FOR EACH ROW DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING
   THEN
        MERGE INTO results rs
        USING (select :new.id id, :new.question_id qid, :new.answer_id aid, :new.student_id stid 
        from dual) t1
          ON (t1.qid = rs.question_id AND t1.stid = rs.student_id)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET rs.answer_id = t1.aid
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (id, question_id, answer_id, student_id)
          VALUES (t1.id, t1.qid, t1.aid, t1.stid);
   END IF;  
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "BIGFIVE"."RESULTS_INSERT" ENABLE;
```

Comment: You can't commit in a trigger. BTW, *which* values are you trying to insert? It is difficult to guess just by looking at your code. Also, you can't manipulate with a table that is just being used (you'll get a mutating table error).

Comment: Updated my question! @Littlefoot

Comment: OK, thank you. But, as I said, that trigger won't return an INVALID NUMBER error but **mutating table** one. Where did you get *invalid number*?

Comment: Sorry, don't know exactly how do you mean where do i get invalid number. I get it in script output. If its help you, trigger gives me this exception: SEVERE 42 116625  uncaught exception for StatusMonitor[RESULTS_INSERT,   0.000,000, Status[50f98354, stale, unknown, 0/0/0/0]] in Thread[status-0,2,main]: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It looks strange, because the table you show in picture and the table you merge into have different columns: with spaces in the picture and without spaces in the code. Is this really an output for the table you use in the code? Please, provide a DDL for your table also so we can reproduce your issue

Comment: Yes, oracle display it like this. Theres a "_" in every column name. I deleted COMIT and now i got this error: SQL Error: ORA-04091: table BIGFIVE.RESULTS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "BIGFIVE.RESULTS_INSERT", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'BIGFIVE.RESULTS_INSERT' like you said @Littlefoot

Comment: Because you cannot do insert into the same table inside trigger, as it will cause infinite cascade of trigger events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I meant: sample table first:

```
SQL> create table results (id number, question_id varchar2(20),
  2  answer_id varchar2(20), student_id varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Trigger with no code, it just commits:

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger results_insert
  3     after INSERT
  4     ON results
  5     FOR EACH ROW DECLARE
  6  BEGIN
  7     commit;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into results(id,question_id, answer_id, student_id) values (1,'qst1', 'answ2', 'stud3');
insert into results(id,question_id, answer_id, student_id) values (1,'qst1', 'answ2', 'stud3')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.RESULTS_INSERT", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.RESULTS_INSERT'
```

---

Your trigger ("as is", I didn't modify anything):

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger results_insert
  3     after INSERT
  4     ON results
  5     FOR EACH ROW DECLARE
  6  BEGIN
  7     IF INSERTING
  8     THEN
  9          MERGE INTO results rs
 10          USING (select :new.id id, :new.question_id qid, :new.answer_id aid, :new.student_id stid
 11          from dual) t1
 12            ON (t1.qid = rs.question_id AND t1.stid = rs.student_id)
 13          WHEN MATCHED THEN
 14            UPDATE SET rs.answer_id = t1.aid
 15          WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 16            INSERT (id, question_id, answer_id, student_id)
 17            VALUES (t1.id, t1.qid, t1.aid, t1.stid);
 18     END IF;
 19     COMMIT;
 20  END;
 21  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into results(id,question_id, answer_id, student_id) values (1,'qst1', 'answ2', 'stud3');
insert into results(id,question_id, answer_id, student_id) values (1,'qst1', 'answ2', 'stud3')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.RESULTS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.RESULTS_INSERT", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.RESULTS_INSERT'
```

Mutating table, not invalid number error.

---

What you **should do** is to use `MERGE` in the first place. Abandon trigger, it brings nothing but *pain*. Just `DROP` it. Then:

Inserting a new row:

```
SQL> merge into results rs
  2    using (select 1 id, 'qst1' qid, 'answ2' aid, 'stud3' stid from dual) t1
  3    on (    t1.qid = rs.question_id
  4        and t1.stid = rs.student_id
  5       )
  6    when matched then update set
  7      rs.answer_id = t1.aid
  8    when not matched then insert (id, question_id, answer_id, student_id)
  9      values (t1.id, t1.qid, t1.aid, t1.stid);

1 row merged.

SQL> select * From results;

        ID QUESTION_ID          ANSWER_ID            STUDENT_ID
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 qst1                 answ2                stud3
```

Matching `question_id` and `student_id` (so that merge performs update; check `answer_id`):

```
SQL> merge into results rs
  2    using (select 1 id, 'qst1' qid, 'answ9' aid, 'stud3' stid from dual) t1
  3    on (    t1.qid = rs.question_id
  4        and t1.stid = rs.student_id
  5       )
  6    when matched then update set
  7      rs.answer_id = t1.aid
  8    when not matched then insert (id, question_id, answer_id, student_id)
  9      values (t1.id, t1.qid, t1.aid, t1.stid);

1 row merged.

SQL> select * From results;

        ID QUESTION_ID          ANSWER_ID            STUDENT_ID
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 qst1                 answ9                stud3

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i already deleted commit from trigger. I have to make it with trigger because im using this with java and insert user's test answers to results table. I want to check if user already answered the questions or not yet. Update his answers if exists insert if not.

Comment: No, you don't *have to* use a trigger. You'd rather use a **stored procedure** which accepts 4 parameters and contains a MERGE statement (just like the one I posted). Then call that procedure from your Java program and pass appropriate parameters.

Comment: Ok, i will do it like this. Thank you for your quick help!